# Mongodb Compare two fields with ratio

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Rows whose field is twice that of the other field
explain with example  :

```
{id : 1 , price : 10 , spent : 5}
{id : 1 , price : 20 , spent : 30}
{id : 1 , price : 40 , spent : 90}
{id : 1 , price : 80 , spent : 200}
```

I want row that spend is equal or bigger twice price (spent >= 2*price)

result :

`{id : 1 , price : 40 , spent : 90}`  ==> *(spent >= 2*price) [90>80]*

`{id : 1 , price : 80 , spent : 200}` ==> *(spent >= 2*price) [160>200]*

please refer suggestion except use **$where**

my mongo cluster have limitations of use **$where**

(**MongoError: $where is not allowed in this atlas tier**)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB documentation is very good with examples.
There is a place [`Reference`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) that has all the operators.
If you haven't found it, maybe try the bellow, i think this is what you need.

Query

- we can refer to the field with `$fieldName`
- and gt/multiply operators are used
- finally `$expr` is used in match when we use aggregate operators (instead of query operaros) like we did here

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=626f16977bf7deec3f506b02)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$match": {"$expr": {"$gt": ["$spent", {"$multiply": [2, "$price"]}]}}}])
```